# How to read json data in php

Tags: php, json

I have a json response like following

```
[{"record_type":"type1","record_name":"name1"},
{"record_type":"type2","record_name":"name2"}]
```

wish to have an output like below.

```
type1 name1
type2 name2
```

Am beginner in json and php. Guys Please help ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP expects us to write all the code for them.

Comment: Pls leave if u r not willing to :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<?php
$jsonData = '[{"record_type":"type1","record_name":"name1"},
             {"record_type":"type2","record_name":"name2"}]';
$phpArray = json_decode($jsonData);
print_r($phpArray);
foreach ($phpArray as $key => $value) {
echo "<p>$value->record_type | $value->record_name</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: The json_decode is returning the result as an Object so you cannot access it directly like an array, It returned the following in the log:
`PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

The correct way to acess the object propery would be :
`echo "<p>$value->record_type | $value->record_name</p>";`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?php

$json = '[{"record_type":"type1","record_name":"name1"},
        {"record_type":"type2","record_name":"name2"}]';
$decodedJson = json_decode($json,true);
foreach ($decodedJson as $value) {
    echo $value['record_type']."  ".$value['record_name'];
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

This will return you the result as follows:

> type1 name1 
> type2 name2

Ref [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score -2):

```
use:
<?php
    json_decode($json_str);
?>
```